# InputStream was Closed before reading in any higher version of tomcat 6.0.18

Tags: tomcat

trying to migrate an application from tomcat 6.0.18 and java 1.6_0.34 to newer version of tomcat, sending an XML snippet in the post request, with any higher version of tomcat, Java InputStream is shown as closed before reading..and works fine with tomcat 6.0.18

does any one heard or faced this issue? hoping to get some guidance

Thanks,
Rishi

Comment: What is your target environment?

Comment: i am able to replicate issue on my local windows but target application is in AWS, java version "1.6.0_34"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.6) (amazon-67.1.13.6.0.69.amzn1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode).

Comment: Rishi. Install your new tomcat version. copy paste all your old projects in webapps and add contents from old server.xml file to newly installed tomcat/conf/server.xml. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Rishi all of those versions seem pretty old. Don't they?